# Search for a specific element in multiple pages and click using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, visual-studio-code, xpath, string.format

Hi im trying to navigate from page 1 to page 5 (the element can be in any of the  pages)and find and click on a specific element using python selenium.
The following is the element from the page:

`<span _ngcontent-mtx-c123"" class"ng-star-inserted">ABC Company</span>`

i tried by using : `driver.find_element_by_name("ABC Company").click()` but this doesnt work.
Another Way i tried:

```
1. element_path="//span[contains(text(),'ABC Company')]" 
2. while True: 
3.  if(driver.find_elements_by_xpath(element_xpath)): driver.find_element_by_xpath(element_xpath).click() 
4.  else: driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath to goto next page").click()
```

I need the code to find element from the next pages until its found and then click it.

is there any other way to do this???

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to check if the element is present and only if it does - click it. Otherwise you will get exception while trying clicking non-existing element.
`driver.find_elements` returns a list of web elements matching the passed locator. So if there are such elements it will return non-empty list interpreted as `True` by Python. Otherwise empty list is returned interpreted as `False`.
As about the locator for the element you are looking for: you can locate the element according to the text it contains. It can be done with XPath.
As following:

```
element_xpath = "//span[contains(text(),'ABC Company')]"
if(driver.find_elements_by_xpath(element_xpath)):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(element_xpath).click()
```

If you need to update the XPath locator dynamically you can pass the text as parameter. Let's say you have a list of texts, you can iterate on them as following:

```
for txt in texts:
    element_xpath = "//span[contains(text(),'{}')]".format(txt)
    if(driver.find_elements_by_xpath(element_xpath)):
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(element_xpath).click()
```

Comment: Just to clarify. There are several elements, there are 5 web pages, some of the elements can appear on those pages such as on each page can present each those elements but you can not know what elements are presenting on each page? Is this a scenario?

Comment: And the elements are located by their texts only. Right?

Comment: Hi Thank you so much.It works awesome.
one more question:
what if i need to give the "ABC Company" as a dynamic variable? element_xpath = "//span[contains(text(),'ABC Company')]"

Comment: I have updated the answer for parametrized texts

Comment: Hi,
i tried the following way:

`element_path="//span[contains(text(),'ABC Company')]"
while True:
if(driver.find_elements_by_xpath(element_xpath)):
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(element_xpath).click()
else: driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath to goto next page").click()`

but this doesn't work.
Can you find any mistake??
if the element is not there on the page it must go to next page until the element is found.

Comment: What exactly "doesn't work" there? I guess you see a kind of exception?

Comment: yes exactly!... getting a error msg like "element not found"

Comment: I guess the error occurs when trying to click the button to go to the next page?

Comment: yes. i too thought the same.. but i tried clicking the page through code without the loop. it goes through.
could you suggest me any changes in the loop?

Comment: I'm asking: when you looping with your code - on what line, where the code fails ?

Comment: Thank you for the reply.
i have updated the code above
im getting the error in line 3: 
Error is : **no such element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[contains(text(),'ABC Company')]"}**

it is not taking the condition after the IF statement.
Could you suggest anything?
Thanks

Comment: Add `time.sleep()` after `driver.find_element_by_xpath(element_xpath).click()` Looks like you validating existence of that element again after clicking on it and since it still not disappeared (immediately a moment after clicking on it) you trying to click on it again and then it is not there... So just add delay between clicking on the element and the next validation / action

Comment: I tried by adding `time.sleep()`. but that is not the problem. its showing the same error. It is something to do with the IF statement.  The code execution stops at the IF and the click below it is not even triggered. What i need is : if the element is not found then it must click the "goto next page until the element is found. Do you know any other method to do this ??
Thankks